# Get last modified date of Folders and Files in Azure Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, pathlib

I need to get last modified dates of all Folders and Files in DBFS mount point (of ADLS Gen1) under Azure Databricks.
Folder structure is like:

```
Not containing any files, Empty folders:
/dbfs/mnt/ADLS1/LANDING/parent/child/subfolder1
/dbfs/mnt/ADLS1/LANDING/parent/child/subfolder2/subfolder3

Containing some files:
/dbfs/mnt/ADLS1/LANDING/parent/XYZ/subfolder4/File1.txt
/dbfs/mnt/ADLS1/LANDING/parent/XYZ/subfolder5/subfolder6/File2.txt
```

Used following Python code to get last modified date:

```
root_dir = "/dbfs/mnt/ADLS1/LANDING/parent"

def get_directories(root_dir):

    for child in Path(root_dir).iterdir():

        if child.is_file():
            print(child, datetime.fromtimestamp(getmtime(child)).date())
      
        else:
            print(child, datetime.fromtimestamp(getmtime(child)).date())
            get_directories(child)
```

From above code, I am getting correct modified date for all folders containing files.

***But for empty folders, it is giving current date. Not last modified date***.

Whereas, when I hardcode the path for empty folder, it is giving correct modified date:

`print(datetime.fromtimestamp(getmtime("/dbfs/mnt/ADLS1/LANDING/parent/child/subfolder1")).date())`

Can someone please help me out, what am I missing here in loop?

Answer (score 0):

Seems, the issue was with processing time.
I given a wait time : `time.sleep(.000005)`.
It worked as expected.